# How to Input Into HTML JEditorPane While Keeping Previous Text?

Tags: java, html, swing, concatenation, jeditorpane

Okay, so the error here is simple, and I completely understand why this isn't working. Basically, I have a `JEditorPane`, which I am using because I need to use things like `<b>` and `<strike>` from HTML, and I wanted to add the text to what was already there, so I used `editorPane.setText(editorPane.getText() + "<p>test</p>");` However, after doing a bit of debugging I figured out that that was actually giving me this:

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Hello
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
<p>test</p>
```

If you know your HTML, you know that the `<p>test</p>` won't show up, since it's not in the `<body>`. This makes sense since `setText(getText() + text)` should only concatenate the two strings. How then can I put the string of choice *inside* the `<body>` then while still keeping everything else that's already in the body?

**Note:** Just so you know, the HTML formatting (like `<head>`, `<html>`) is put there automatically, and so all that formatting is already there when I set the text to "Hello".

Comment: Your problem is that you try to concatinate your text onto your HTML-structure.
What you probaply want to do is, to substitute, or insert a Tag in your existing structure.

Answer (score 1):

Use the JEditorPane’s [Document object](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getDocument()):

```
HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument) editorPane.getDocument();
try {
    Element lastElement = doc.getParagraphElement(doc.getLength() - 1);
    doc.insertAfterEnd(lastElement, "<p>test</p>");
} catch (BadLocationException | IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, this solution isn't very ideal, but it will work for my purposes. What I'll do, is just make a `String` and then add everything into that, and then once all of the text is in, then add that to the `JEditorPane`. Also I imagine this could be done by splitting via `<` or `/`, and then just going x through where x is a preset number plus how many items there are.

Comment: Your alternative solution is not so far of the track. See my solution for how to use a Patternmatcher.
This way you will be able to replace any Tag needed.